# Converting a part of a char array to string in java

Tags: java, string, char

I have a character array:

`char[] a = {'I', ' ', 'm', 'i', 's', 's', ' ', 'y', 'o', 'u', '.'};`

Now I want to convert a part of that character array(for example:'m', 'i', 's', 's') to a string.
How can I do that?

Comment: how do you determine which par of it is to be converted ?

Comment: if you have a `char[] a`, then a `String str = new String(a)` would work. Then you could just take a substring.

Comment: This might be useful: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html

Answer (score 19):

You want to create a String. How about looking at [the javadoc of String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html), find the constructors, and finding this one:

> String(char[] value, int offset, int count)
>
> Allocates a new String that contains characters from a subarray of the character array argument.

Answer (score 16):

Try the [`String(char[], int, int)` constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String%28char%5B%5D,%20int,%20int%29):

```
String s = new String(a, 2, 4);
```

That will construct a `String` from the characters of array `a` starting at offset 2 and a length of 4.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to convert the whole char array you should do

`String s = new String(a);`

Answer (score 0):

First I want to know that you want which part of char array

there are so many way to get part  of that array

First

```java
String s = new String(a);
```

Second you can get part of array as mention below

```java
public class Test2 {

    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        char[] a = {'I', ' ', 'm', 'i', 's', 's', ' ', 'y', 'o', 'u', '.'};
        String s = new String(a);
        System.out.println("Whole Array :- "+s);
        String[] array = s.split(" ");
        System.out.println("\n Part Of Array");
        for (String string : array) {
            System.out.println(string);
        }

    }

}
```